# Error 400 (Bad Request) from Json post containing double-precision numbers

Tags: json, xamarin.android, double

I'm sending regular posts to a server which is storing the resulting data in a database. A lot of the time, the server is returning a 400 error, which appears to mean that the post was malformed. But I can tell (from the fact that the correct data is stored in the database) that sometimes the server has acecpted the data.
The Json is very simple, and pretty much the same every time, e.g.

{"latitude":50.2905,"longitude":5.04548,"recorded_at":"20200925 21:07:31","owner":1}.

Sometimes it's accepted without error. The errors occur if the data is sent via WiFi/Broadband or via 4G.
The (Xamarin) code sending the data is as follows:

```
    private string UploadResult(WebClient client, double lat, double lng, DateTime t)
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";

        lat = Math.Round(lat, 5);
        lng = Math.Round(lng, 5);
        json = string.Format("{{\"latitude\":{0},\"longitude\":{1},\"recorded_at\":\"{2}\",\"owner\":{3}}}",
            lat, lng, DBTime(t), MyLocation.owner);
        Uri uri = new Uri(UrlBase.urlBase + "SaveLocation");
        string result = client.UploadString(uri, json);
        return result;
    }
```

I don't have access to the server to debug it, only to look at the database entries. It's a WCF service storing data in a MSSQL database, and the lat/longs are stored as decimal(10,6). I'm fairly sure that the problem is recent, even though the relevant code hasn't changed - I wasn't getting these errors (not noticeably anyway) earlier.

I did a lot of searching around here and tried plenty of code changes, all of which had no effect. I had the same problem with different versions of Visual Stuio, Xamarin and Android API levels.

Eventually I tried reducing the precision of the latitude and longitude before posting, i.e.

```
        lat = Math.Round(lat, 1);
        lng = Math.Round(lng, 1);
```

and Bingo!, all is well (except for the accuracy of my database of course). Having 2 decimal places or more brings back the error(s).

Clearly the server code could be changed to accept integers only, and send the data differently, but that's going to be tricky. What can I change in the client code to address this?

[later]
I tried adding the correct string format for decimal numbers

```
        json = string.Format("{{\"latitude\":{0:0.0000},\"longitude\":{1:0.0000},\"recorded_at\":\"{2}\",\"owner\":{3}}}", ....
```

but that made no difference. Interestingly, I also tried sending the numbers as strings

```
        json = string.Format("{{\"latitude\":\"{0}\",\"longitude\":\"{1}\",\"recorded_at\":\"{2}\",\"owner\":{3}}}", ......
```

and that was accepted just as much, but with the same error frequency. As I understand it, the numeric data should have been rejected as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing WebClient to HttpClient. I knw WebClient is old tech, but I wrote the original code ages ago and it certainly used to work OK.

```
    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadResult(double lat, double lng, DateTime t)
    {
        lat = Math.Round(lat, 5);
        lng = Math.Round(lng, 5);
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string json = string.Format("{{\"latitude\":{0:0.00000},\"longitude\":{1:0.00000},\"recorded_at\":\"{2}\",\"owner\":{3}}}",
            lat, lng, DBTime(t), Location.owner);
            var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            Uri uri = new Uri(UrlBase.urlBase + "SaveLocation");
            try
            {
               response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (response == null)
                {
                    response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                }
                response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                response.ReasonPhrase = string.Format("Post failed: {0}", ex.Message);

            }
            return response;

        }
    }
```

Need to call this function with **await** as well.